# best way to search keywords for games

Tags: unity-game-engine, keyword-search

Can anyone tell me what is the best tool to search keywords for games in Google play store, Apple app store and Amazon store? I have searched google but didn't get and fruitful results. Need suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

I found these tools. I don't know whether it would be helpful. Good luck.

- https://keywordtool.io/app-store
- https://www.wordstream.com/keywords
- Google Adwords Keyword Planner
- https://yoast.com/keyword-research-tools/
- https://www.semrush.com/lp/keyword-research/en/
- https://keywordtool.io/
- https://kwfinder.com/
- https://trends.google.com/trends/
- http://buzzsumo.com/

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check it. Let me know if it was helpful.  Regards :) @AbidUllah

Comment: Helping would give negative votes . Amazing. Bloody hell

Comment: Well I tried to upvote your answer.Someone else might have given a negative vote.

Comment: Your answer is helpful. Thank You for the help.

Comment: @AbidUllah Upvote my answer or mark my answer so someone will find useful